# extracting list of parent and children from a table using mysql

Tags: mysql, parent-child

I want to extract a list of user sorted by parent and each of it's children after the parent from a table like this:

```
id  | name | parent_id
----| ---- | --------
 1  |  max |    0
 2  |  john|    0
 3  |  jim |    1
 4  |  jack|    1
 5  | merry|    2
```

and i want a query to extract each parent and then its children: like this

```
 max
    Jim
    jack
 john
    merry
```

i can do it with to loop inside each other. but i search if there is a sql query solution.
i also tested the way using join table with itself presented below by @Tucker but it return this:
it is near but not just what i want. it retrieve this:

```
-------------
max  |  jim
max  |jack
john |merry
---------------------
```

but i want for example

```
-----------------
0    |max
max  |Jim
max  |jack
0    |john
john |merry
------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

my syntax might be slightly off, but you could join the table on itself like this

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT a.name AS `PARENT`, b.name AS `CHILD`
FROM db.table a 
JOIN db.table b ON b.parent_id=a.id 
WHERE a.parent_id=0
UNION ALL
SELECT c.parent_id AS `PARENT`,c.name AS `CHILD`
FROM db.table c WHERE c.parent_id=0 
);
```

The row ordering you have in your example would be awkward to achieve through sql.

Comment: it is near but not just what i want. it retrieve this:<br>
-------------<br>
max  |  jim<br>
max  |jack<br>
john |merry<br>
but i want for example
-----------------
0    |max
max  |Jim
max  |jack
0    |john
john |merry
------------------

Comment: @MAliFahimi i'd recommend ordering through code and not sql.  you won't gracefully get the ordering you want with sql